# Finding lua addresses with ida

Tags: ida, lua

I tried to find lua_pcall, lua_newthread, luaL_loadbuffer, lua_tolstring, lua_pushcclosure and lua_pushinteger functions with IDA decompiler but I didn't find them. Can someone please tell me what is best way to find this lua functions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Please edit your question to include more information. All we can guess from your question is that you're using IDA (with Hex-Rays plugin) to reverse engineer something you believe or know to contain Lua code. How about creating your own signatures to recognize Lua?

Comment: I found the way to locate luaL_loadbuffer, lua_tolstring, lua_pushcclosure and lua_pushinteger and other functions through core lua functions(collectgarbage, dofile, error, gcinfo) but problem is if exe or dll are packed I can't locate those core lua functions